# Sort starting with different order

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

In the following, the results are the same:

```
[3, 5].sort{|a, b| b <=> a}
[5, 3].sort{|a, b| b <=> a}
```

I would like to know what happened internally and how it depends on input array.

Comment: The two lines of code you posted sort two different permutations of the elements of the same array. They **must** produce the same outcome (sort the values according to your sorting rules).

Comment: @axiac  could you please explain how the sort block is going to evaluate. I think it depends on the input array

Comment: If they give different results, what is the purpose of sorting?

Comment: @sawa I'm looking for explanation. I just accepted Stefan answer. Please have a look at once

Comment: @pramod of course it depends of the input array but the purpose of [`Array#sort()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) is to return an array that contains the same values as the input array in a specified order. As long as you use the same sorting rules (`b <=> a` in this case), `#sort()` must always return the same result, no matter the order of values in the input array. That's the only reason `Array#sort()` exists.

Comment: @axiac: Actually, `Enumerable#sort` and `Enumerable#sort_by` are not stable, so it is in fact *not* guaranteed that the result is always the same. It is in fact not even guaranteed to be the same for *the same* input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line:

```
[3, 5].sort { |a, b| b <=> a }
```

Invokes the block with `a = 3` and `b = 5`. It returns the result of `5 <=> 3` which is `1`. An integer greater than `0` tells `sort` that `a` follows `b`. The result is therefore `[5, 3]`.

---

The second line:

```
[5, 3].sort { |a, b| b <=> a }
```

Invokes the block with `a = 5` and `b = 3`. It returns the result of `3 <=> 5` which is `-1`. An integer less than `0` tells `sort` that `b` follows `a`. The result is therefore (again) `[5, 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are sorting an array, and changing the array's elements order does not change the sorting result.

This is the whole point of sorting after all - to get *sorted* result despite the initial arrays ordering.

To change the result, you will want to change the sorting rule, not the array.

Comment: It make sense to me, could you please explain how the block is going to evaluate. I think it depends on the input array.

Comment: @pramod [please see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637419/how-does-arraysort-work-when-a-block-is-passed) on the `sort` with block explanation. It does not depend on the "input array" :)

Answer (score 1):

The output is the same regardless of the input order because you sorting the array.

If you want to sort with the opposite order write

```
[3,5].sort{|a,b| a <=> b}
```