# Confused with Ruby's <=> operator

Tags: ruby, spaceship-operator

I am confused with Ruby's <=> operator. How does it differ from == or ===? Any comprehensive examples/use case? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called the 'spaceship' operator. More info: [What is the Ruby <=> (spaceship) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/ruby-spaceship-operator) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator

Comment: how about in this code snippet, this confused me the most. assuming a = [ "d", "a", "e", "c", "b" ] how does this work, exactly? a.sort {|x,y| y <=> x }

Answer (score 14):

`<=>` is the combined comparison operator. it returns 0 if LHS equals RHS, 1 if LHS is greater than the RHS and -1 if LHS is less than RHs

Answer (score 2):

== will NOT work in sort for example

`[3,5,6,2,7].sort{|x,y| x <=>y }`

== returns Boolean 
<=> returns Fixnum (-1,0,1)

Comment: I'm assuming -1 is the same as false, and 1 is the same as true. But how does it work in this example?