# How to sort file names in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, file, sorting, numbers

Yes it is a duplicate of [Is there a natural_sort_by method for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078906/is-there-a-natural-sort-by-method-for-ruby)
, but i think dawg and Eric made it clearer here, at least to me these answers are more exhaustive..

I have an array like this:

```
arr = ["file1.txt", "file11.txt", "file12.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]
```

And i want it to be sorted like this:

```
arr = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file11.txt", "file12.txt"]
```

How can i do this? I tried with `sort`, but it's not very clear to me..

I sorted the files by size like this:

```
files=Dir.entries("./").sort { |f| File.size(f) }.select { |f| File.file?(f) }
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough, sorting by file name in ubuntu actually does sort in correct order. But sorting in ruby make it go like file1, file10, file11, file12, file2, file3. This is also wierd

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819911/sort-and-list-the-files-from-a-directory-in-numeric-order

Comment: Check out https://github.com/rwz/natural_sort. It works perfectly and all you need to do is `.sort(NaturalSort)`. Easy peezie, lemon squeezie!

Comment: Correction, that should be `.sort(&NaturalSort)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eric's answer is great way of doing a [Natural Sort Order](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) for the digits only in file names. Works if all file names have the same prefix.

If you want to add a second element (for example, file names that do not have digits in them) you can great a multi-element sort_by be creating a list:

```
filenames = ["file1.txt", "file11.txt", "file12.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt","file.txt", "File.txt"]
filenames.sort_by{ |name| [name[/\d+/].to_i, name] }
=> ["File.txt", "file.txt", "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file11.txt", "file12.txt"]
```

The two element of the `sort_by` implements:

1. Integer value of digits if any are found with a regex `name[/\d+/].to_i` then
2. Name if no digits or same digits `name`.

More robustly, you can split the entire string by digits and convert each to an int:

```
> "abc123def456gh".split(/(\d+)/).map{ |e| Integer(e) rescue e}
=> ["abc", 123, "def", 456, "gh"]
```

So your Natural Sort becomes:

```
arr.sort_by{ |s| s.split(/(\d+)/).map{ |e| Integer(e) rescue e}}
```

So now names and numbers (even multiples names and numbers) are handled correctly:

```
> arr = ["file1.txt", "file11.txt", "file12.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "gfile10.txt", "gfile1.txt", "gfile.txt", "file.txt", "afile.txt","afile10.txt","afile2.txt" ]
> arr.sort_by{ |s| s.split(/(\d+)/).map{ |e| Integer(e) rescue e}}
=> ["afile2.txt", "afile10.txt", "afile.txt", "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file11.txt", "file12.txt", "file.txt", "gfile1.txt", "gfile10.txt", "gfile.txt"]
```

Comment: This works, but as i commented on question, ubuntu sorts the files fine if we do sort by name. So my guess is there must be something built in in ruby which could be used for this. For now, i have no choice but to use your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the first number out of the filename, convert it to an integer and use it inside `sort_by`:

```
filenames = ["file1.txt", "file11.txt", "file12.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]
filenames.sort_by{ |name| name[/\d+/].to_i }
# ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file11.txt", "file12.txt"]
```

`/\d+/` is a regex which means "a sequence of 1 or more digits":

```
"test123"[/\d+/]
# => "123"
"test"[/\d+/]
# => nil
```

Note that it only sorts by number and ignores the rest:

```
["a2", "b1", "z3"].sort_by{ |name| name[/\d+/].to_i }
# => ["b1", "a2", "z3"]
```

Comment: You might add that this is called a [Natual Sort](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/)

Comment: Thanks for your replies!! Can i ask to explain this please? `name[/\d+/]`

Comment: This does not sort names with different characters leading up to the digits btw

Comment: @dawg: Indeed, I added a note. More info would be needed to know what to do with `a2.txt` and `b1.txt`