# Placing items in an array into div classes based on size of element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, html

I have an array of things, `things = [1, 500, 900, 0, -105, -8, 16, 4]` and I want to display them in red, green or black in my view based on whether they're larger than zero, smaller than zero or equal to zero.

Right now my code looks like:

```
<%= @things.each do |p|%>
 <% if p > 0 %>
      <%= p  %>
    <% elsif p < 0 %>
      <%= p %>
    <% else %>
      <%= p %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not displaying the numbers correctly to start, and I've gone through a few iterations of putting them in divs and nothing seems to work. Once I get 'em in classes, I can add colors pretty easily. (I also need to keep them in the same order they're in in the array)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's the issue here

```
 <% @things.each do |p|
     if p < 0
       class_name = 'red'
     elsif p > 0 
       class_name = 'green'
     else 
       class_name = 'black'
     end %>
     <div class="<%=class_name%>"><%= p %></div> 
<% end %>
```

Then css :

```
.red{color:red;}
.green{color:green;}
.black{color:black;}
```

Edit : In your example, you were using `<%= @things.each`. Don't use `<%=` for things that are not supposed to output anything

Comment: Thanks. No real issue, just been thinking about this for too long and my brain kind of stopped working.

Comment: See my answer for a slightly more terse way to get over/under/equals 0 using the [spaceship operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/ruby-spaceship-operator).

Comment: Also, note that using CSS class names that describe the style you wish to impart is [generally a bad idea](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticselector). +1, however, for providing a working solution.

Comment: I agree with you, except that sometimes it can come in handy for short-straight-forward declarations. For example, I like to declare a class called `clear` that `clear:both;` to quickly apply it on some elements

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto My Rails app is angry - `syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif, expecting keyword_end
     elsif p > 0 `

Comment: Note also that if you wanted the case but not the spaceship you could do `case true; when p<0 then ...; when p>0 then ...; else ...; end`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can think of is build a view helper

```
def set_color number 
  case
    when number == 0 
       "black"
    when number > 0
       "green"
    when number < 0
       "red"
  end
end
```

and in the view

```
<% @things.each do |p|%>
<div class="<%= set_color(p)%>"> <%= p %> </div>
<% end %>
```

Finally do the CSS

Comment: +1 for working, but -1 for terrible style. Remove every `return` statement from that method and you get the same result but more idiomatic code.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want them grouped by positive/negative/0

```
<% @things.group_by{ |n| n<=>0 }.sort.each do |sign,items|%>
  <ul class="<%= sign==-1 ? 'negative' : sign==1 ? 'positive' : 'zero'%>">
    <% items.each do |item| %>
      <li><%= item></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

#### If you want them in array order, just classed

```
<ul>
  <% @things.each do |thing|
    css = case thing <=> 0
      when -1 then "negative"
      when  0 then "zero"
      when  1 then "positive"
    end
    %>
    <li class="<%=css%>"><%= thing %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Note that you incorrectly have an equals sign at the start of your `each` wrapper:

```
<%= @things
```

...which will cause the `to_s` representation of the entire array to be output (you don't want that).