# Operator <=> in Ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Ruby <=> (spaceship) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator)

I saw a code and an operator I'm unfamiliar with

```
 @array << {:suffix=> substring, :index => i}
 @array.sort! { |x,y| x[:suffix] <=> y[:suffix]}
```

I can't do google on it. What does `<=>` do?

Comment: [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3C%3D%3E) is your friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does comparison defined for the particular class. If it is the case that `... < ...` is true, it returns `-1`, if `... == ...` is true, then `0`, and if `... > ...` is true, then `1`.

Comment: There's a link in my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

This is [the spaceship operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator), it was borrowed from Perl. It is commonly used for sorting, because it returns -1 if left operand is less than right operand, 1 if right operand is greater than the left and returns 0 otherwise.

```
1 <=> 2 # => -1
2 <=> 1 # => 1
1 <=> 1 # => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called [the spaceship operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator)

For the core numeric and string classes, it's a comparison operator that returns -1, 0, or 1.

In theory, a class can define any operator to do anything it wants, but this will be the method that is used when sorting. It may make sense to define `<=>` for an arbitrary application class if that class will ever need to be ordered.