# Method <=> and others questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just began to learn ruby on rails.
I'm doing a tutorial at the moment, but I'm also trying to understand the code that one of my collegue did. I have looked for the answers on internet but did not find any response which was answering my questions.
So here are my questions :

On this code :

```
class Post
  require 'date'
  include Comparable
  attr_accessor :post_number, :author, :date

  def initialize

  end

  def <=> (another_post)
    self.date <=> another_post.date
  end
end
```

What does the method "<=>" means? Is it a copy of :post_number, :author and a change of :date? It seems that this method is not working anyway, but I'm just wondering the meaning of this method.

Second question : 
I found this code : 
a, b and c have proper value.

```
a = 0.1 * b if c?
```

Is this any different of :

```
if c?
  a = 0.1 * b
end
```

Well, thank you for your answers and I hope that my questions are not too stupid.
Regards,
Bdloul

Comment: For your first question, see [What is the Ruby Spaceship operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator) For your second question, yes they are equivalent.

Comment: Next time ask questions separately and try to give them meaningful titles -- it allows to build up knowledge base that can be later easily browsed by other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<=>` is the comparator method. If you did something like `Post.all.sort`, the `sort` method will look to see if `Post` defines a way to compare post objects. Otherwise, it will move up the inheritance hierarchy until it finds a way to sort them.

The `<=>` looks weird, but it's just a combination of `<` (is one object less than another object), `=` (are two objects equal), and `>` (is one object greater than the other).

So in your posted code, the author is making a method that will define how to compare two objects. In particular, he wrote that the way they will be compared is based on the way the `.date` attribute is compared. So in other words, a Post starting on January 1, 2013 will come before a post starting January 2, 2013, and so on.

As for the next part, the two pieces of code are identical. In Ruby, you can write many conditions on a single line. These are also all equivalent, just to give more examples:

```
# 1.
a = 1 unless a == 0
# or
unless a == 0
  a = 1
end

# 2.
a += 1 while a < 10
# or
while a < 10
  a += 1
end
```

Comment: Your example of modificator notation is wrong -- using extended version behaves differently when `a` variable is not defined.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to imply that a was already defined. I was not concerned with the code around the examples, just showing examples of the conditions themselves.

Comment: My point is that modifier notation is very convenient, but it is not identical to extended notation.

Comment: In the question, it is clearly stated that "a, b and c have proper value."

Comment: @Bdloul you're welcome! Remember to mark it as the answer to your question!

Answer (score -1):

`<=>` is a comparison operator. See [What is the Ruby <=> (spaceship) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator)

The `if` statements are equivalent.