# What does <=> method do?

Tags: ruby

I want to know what is the meaning of `def <=>(other)` in ruby methods. I want to know what is the `<=>` in ruby method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<=>` is not "in" Ruby method, `#<=>` is a Ruby method. This method is used for comparable objects (members of ordered sets) to easily gain implementation of `#<`, `#>`, `#==` etc. methods by including `Comparable` mixin.

```
class GradeInFiveLevelScale
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :grade
  def initialize grade; @grade = grade end
  def <=> other; other.grade <=> grade end
  def to_s; grade.to_s end
end

a = GradeInFiveLevelScale.new 1
b = GradeInFiveLevelScale.new 1
c = GradeInFiveLevelScale.new 3

a > b #=> false
a >= b #=> true
a > c #=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

<=> is the combined comparison operator. It returns 0 if first operand equals second, 1 if first operand is greater than the second and -1 if first operand is less than the second.

More info on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator).