# Is x more, less or equal to the value y?

Tags: ruby, comparison

What would be the most the concise way to express the following in Ruby:

Is x more, less or equal to the value y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do as below using [***spaceship operator***(`<=>`)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) :

> Returns 0 if obj and other are the same object or obj `==` other, otherwise `nil`.
>
> The `<=>`  is used by various methods to compare objects, for example `Enumerable#sort`, `Enumerable#max` etc.
>
> Your implementation of `<=>` should return one of the following values: `-1, 0, 1` or `nil`. `-1` means `self` is smaller than other. 0 means self is equal to other. `1` means `self` is bigger than other. `Nil` means the two values could not be compared.

```
x <=> y
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)
Check this out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator

Comment: It will return `-1` if x is less than y, `0` if they are equal and `1` if x is larger than y.