# Sort row of a CSV file by first value

Tags: ruby

**Stock data.csv**

```
1425904377,22532.1309,22533.6992,22524.0703,22524.0703,0
1425904438,22533.4395,22533.4395,22529.2793,22532.2207,0
1425904499,22531.8809,22536.0801,22531.8809,22533.2793,0
1425904559,22532.4297,22534.7207,22530.7598,22532.0996,0
1425904618,22535.7695,22535.9297,22530.6094,22532.2500,0
1425904679,22536.0703,22539.2598,22535.5605,22535.6094,0
1425904738,22542.8809,22544.2305,22536.3594,22536.3594,0
1425904797,22540.6504,22544.0391,22538.5000,22542.9707,0
1425904857,22545.2891,22552.5098,22538.5898,22538.9004,0
1425904860,22547.0703,22547.0703,22547.0703,22547.0703,0
```

I have to do two things:

1. Sort row by `timestamp` (first value)
2. Delete duplicate (key: `timestamp`)

I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
my_csv = CSV.read("public/#{symbol}.csv")
my_csv.sort_by!(&:first)


open("public/#{symbol}.csv", 'w') { |f|
  my_csv.each do |row|
    f.puts "#{row.join(",")}"
  end
}
```

Comment: What is `csv_data` supposed to be? It is never defined.

Comment: `sort_by` is non mutating meaning it creates a new sorted Array. thus when you call each afterwards the array is no longer sorted. You can use `sort_by!` e.g. `csv_data.sort_by!(&:first)`.

Comment: Thanks, now it's works. And do you know how to remove duplicate also?

Comment: If the time stamp has duplicate does it matter which line is kept?

Comment: yes, it doesn't matter if the timestamp is duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'csv'
my_csv = CSV.read 'data.csv'

my_csv.sort! { |a, b| a[0].to_i <=> b[0].to_i }
my_csv.uniq!(&:first)

my_csv.each { |line| p line }
```

Output:

```
["1425904377", "22532.1309", "22533.6992", "22524.0703", "22524.0703", "0"]
["1425904438", "22533.4395", "22533.4395", "22529.2793", "22532.2207", "0"]
["1425904499", "22531.8809", "22536.0801", "22531.8809", "22533.2793", "0"]
["1425904559", "22532.4297", "22534.7207", "22530.7598", "22532.0996", "0"]
["1425904618", "22535.7695", "22535.9297", "22530.6094", "22532.2500", "0"]
["1425904679", "22536.0703", "22539.2598", "22535.5605", "22535.6094", "0"]
["1425904738", "22542.8809", "22544.2305", "22536.3594", "22536.3594", "0"]
["1425904797", "22540.6504", "22544.0391", "22538.5000", "22542.9707", "0"]
["1425904857", "22545.2891", "22552.5098", "22538.5898", "22538.9004", "0"]
["1425904860", "22547.0703", "22547.0703", "22547.0703", "22547.0703", "0"]
```

- `CSV.read` will read the file as an Array
- We can use `sort` with a callback, in the callback we get 2 items to compare
- We compare the first item (the timestamp), we convert it to integer, to make sure we get an integer comparison.
- We use the ["spaceship operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator) for comparison; which will return 0, 1, or -1 (see link), which is what `sort` expects the block to return.
- We use `uniq!` to modify the Array in-place, use this by the first entry.

Comment: What does (:&first) do? What if I want it to be the 208th value? should I write &:twohundredandeigth. I'm not criticising, I just don't understand. Please help.

Comment: @user3505901 `my_csv.uniq!(&:method_name)` is a shortcut for doing `my_csv.uniq! { |c| c.method_name }`. The `first` method is the same as using `[0]`, except that it looks a bit nicer in my opinion. You could also use `my_csv.uniq! { |c| c[0] }`, and if you want to get the 208th value, you could use `c[208]` :-) In standard Ruby, only `first` and `last` work, although Ruby on Rails defines a few more (`second`, `third`, etc.)