# Why do we need spaceship operator?

Tags: ruby

If we have `<`, `>`, and `==`, the total order is determined by those. Why do we need `<=>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator

Comment: See the 2nd answer in the link provided by @AndreyDeineko.  By implementing `<=>` and including the `Comparable` module you get all sorts of nice stuff.

Comment: @pjs, answers to SO questions don't respond to `<=>`, insofar as order of appearance is concerned. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Should have said 2nd most popular...

Answer (score 1):

we **Don't** need [`<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

```
a<=>b
```

is equivalent to:

```
if a<b
  return -1
elsif a>b 
  return 1
else
  return 0
end
```

It is there for convenience and it was taken from perl.

Comment: I don't understand your point. We certainly need the method `<=>` as other built-in methods rely on it. And yes, the result of `<=>` could be obtained in other ways, but the same could be said about nearly all built-in methods.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I see your point. The way I understood the question, OP was confused about what `<=>` did. To me it seemed like he was under the impression that <=> let you do something you could't do with `<`,`>`, and `=`. That was the premise under which I chose my wording.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I mean't "don't need" the same way we "don't need" `or` because we have `not` + `and`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think LukeP means "we don't need [to explicitly define] `<=>` [given that `<`, `==`, and `>` are defined]."

Answer (score 0):

`<=>` is the basis of [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Comparable.html), so you don't have to implement all of the compare functions yourself. It's easier and less error-prone to just implement one function instead of three.

Answer (score -1):

The "spaceship" operator is for **comparison**, not **equality**. It's similar in concept to C's [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function.

From the [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) class:

> `string <=> other_string` → -1, 0, +1 or nil
>
> Comparison — Returns -1, 0, +1 or nil depending on whether string is less than, equal to, or greater than other_string.

In short, `==` returns a boolean expressing equality, while `<=>` returns a number expressing comparative value. If the first object is of greater value than the second, `<=>` returns `+1`. If it's of lesser value, `-1` is returned. If the two have the same value, `0` is returned.

The "value" of an object can be defined to be just about anything. For `String`, however, `<=>` checks the [lexicographic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order/) of the two arguments.

Therefore:

```
"abc" == "abc" # true
("abc" <=> "abc") == 0 # true
```

Answer (score -1):

This operator is sometimes called a "signum" function. It provides the most concise way to customize sort order. For example:

```
require "ostruct"

# Fake "rows" with OpenStructs
my_data = [
    OpenStruct.new({ :name => "Ben", :age => 50 }),
    OpenStruct.new({ :name => "Abe", :age => 50 }),
    OpenStruct.new({ :name => "Cab", :age => 51 })
]

# Sort by age descending, then name ascending
puts my_data.sort { |a, b| 2 * (b.age <=> a.age) + (a.name <=> b.name) }
```

This works because the value from `<=>` is always -1, 0, or 1. I don't know of a more efficient way to do general-purpose sorting.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that there is redundancy between `<`, `==`, `>` and `<=>`. In fact, when `<`, `==`, `>` are defined, `<=>` is automatically defined.