# Sorting a hash by value then by key (but the key is reversed)

Tags: ruby, sorting

The title says it all.

```
total = {"Bob"=>37, "Alice"=>42, "Carl"=>42}
```

I want to sort it by value, and then by key, but with the key in descending order.

Like this:

```
{"Bob"=>37, "Carl"=>42, "Alice"=>42}
```

I tried:

```
return total.sort_by { |k, v| [v, k] }
```

But from here I don't know how to reverse `k`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort):

```
total = {"Bob"=>37, "Alice"=>42, "Carl"=>42}
total.sort { |(k1, v1), (k2, v2)| [v1, k2] <=> [v2, k1] }.to_h
# => {"Bob"=>37, "Carl"=>42, "Alice"=>42}
```

First, sort by values (`v1 <=> v2`) and then reverse sort by keys (`k2 <=> k1`), and since we need it simultaneously, put it into array.

EDIT: @Mirror318, it just looks scary, take a look at the excellent explanation here: [What is the Ruby <=> (spaceship) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator)

Comment: This makes me want to crawl into a corner >< how do you wrap your head around all this?

Comment: @Mirror318 `sort_by { |x| x }` is roughly equivalent to `sort { |a, b| a <=> b }`. Expand your code accordingly, and you almost have the answer.

Comment: Mirror, it won't be long before you will see this as routine.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
total.sort_by { |k,v| [-v,k] }.reverse.to_h
  #=> {"Bob"=>37, "Carl"=>42, "Alice"=>42}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using ruby >= 2.1, then just call `to_h` on sorted array of tuples:

```
total = {"Bob"=>37, "Alice"=>42, "Carl"=>42}
total.sort_by{|k, v| [v, k]}.to_h
```

Else call `Hash.new`:

```
total = {"Bob"=>37, "Alice"=>42, "Carl"=>42}
Hash.new total.sort_by{|k, v| [v, k]}.to_h
```

Comment: That doesn't sort the keys in descending order.