# Search in ruby on rails with value return from method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to sort a set of object s, where s class has an instance method called `some_method` defined in Model of S that returns a value v.

```
def some_method(id)
  ...
  return something # a float number
end
```

Class S is related to class C with many_to_many relation. (class C has_many s and class S has_many c). I get this set of s objects by calling C.find(c_id).s

I am trying something like this

```
C.find(c_id).s.sort{|a,b| a.some_method(id) <=> b.some_method(id)}
```

but I fail to sort the array. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Does it work if you rename the method `method`? I think you may be overridding the built-in `method` method, which could have unintended side-effects: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-method

Comment: It is not called "method", sorry for confusion

Comment: is you method really a class method? or a normal instance method?

Comment: Changed that, sry for confusion

Comment: What is the error that you encounter? If not, what is the (simplified) input given and what result does it return?

Comment: no error occurs, but the sort has no effect. Say for example I sort a group of users selected from database, order by user_id in ascending order, after calling sort on users the result is still order by user_id in ascending order

Comment: I've tried a similar query with my current setup and it sorts the collection accordingly. I believe you're aware that your sorting is not in place, right? Also, where does `id` come from? You can also check the output of `C.find(c_id).s` by appending `.map { |obj| obj.some_method(id) }`, then compare it with the output of your sorting by appending the same `map` as before. This is just to be sure the collection _really_ didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `<=>` operator but seem to be returning floats. That's not what that operator needs to sort effectively. ([Read more about that operator here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/827656/5129208))

I suggest you use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

```
C.find(c_id).s.sort_by{ |element| element.some_method(id) }
```

This will sort the array `s` on the method `some_method`, assuming you have an `id` that you pass in. Depending on what `id` is, you might need to define it outside this block.

Comment: this is not working... well to be more specific, class S is related to class C with a many_to_many relationship. I get this ArrayOfS by calling C.find(c_id).s  (class C has_many s and class S has many c). Will that be different?

Comment: Could you paste your S and C classes in the original question and I'll update my answer to help?