# Combined Comparison / "Spaceship" Operator (<=>) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, operators, comparison-operators, spaceship-operator

Ruby has something called a Combined Comparison or "Spaceship" Operator, it looks like this: `<=>`

It does the following:

```
a <=> b :=
    if a < b then return -1
    if a = b then return  0
    if a > b then return  1
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/827656/5620297)

Is there a similar Operator in Javascript? If not, how can I end up with the same result?

---

**@madox2** suggested using `Math.sign(a - b)`, which works for number, but not arrays (to compare arrays you need to use `array.length`).

It also does not work in Internet Explorer, Safari or all Mobile Browsers (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign#Browser_compatibility))

---

**@duques_l** found a function [here](http://sabrelabs.com/post/48201437312/javascript-spaceship-operator). It works very well, you can test it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pvgfkq7/)

The only problem is if the strings are not comparable the function returns `-1` instead of `nil`

Update: **@duques_l** changed the function a bit and now it works fine (I think so anyway, here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pvgfkq7/3/)):

```
function spaceship(val1, val2) {
    if ((val1 === null || val2 === null) || (typeof val1 != typeof val2)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (typeof val1 === 'string') {
        return (val1).localeCompare(val2);
    }
    else {
        if (val1 > val2) { return 1 }
        else if (val1 < val2) { return -1 }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: doesn't exist, but http://sabrelabs.com/post/48201437312/javascript-spaceship-operator

Comment: @duques_l Interesting link. That function does seem to do just that!

Answer (score 38):

As far as I know there is no such operator in JavaScript but you can use [Math.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) function:

```
Math.sign(a - b);
```

NOTE: As was mentioned in comments, Math.sign() is **not currently supported by all browsers.** Check for compatibility ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign#Browser_compatibility)).

Comment: This works for numbers, but not arrays (well, you have to use `array.length`). Clever solution though!

Comment: if there is one, not in ie.

Comment: @NinaScholz If there is one what?

Comment: @Druzion, the Internet Explorer does not have `Math.sign()`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Ah yes, it is also not supported in Safari and all Mobile Browsers, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)

Comment: As of today and according to CanIUse.com : [Math.sign is supported by almost 95% browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=Math.sign).

If your target clients is that guys who update their browsers, you can assume it's now safe to use it.

Comment: For those desperate to support Legacy Browsers: `if(!Math.sign) Math.sign=function(value) {return value?(value<0?-1:1):0};` will do for a polyfill.

Answer (score 9):

from: http://sabrelabs.com/post/48201437312/javascript-spaceship-operator

improved version:

```
function spaceship(val1, val2) {
  if ((val1 === null || val2 === null) || (typeof val1 != typeof val2)) {
    return null;
  }
  if (typeof val1 === 'string') {
    return (val1).localeCompare(val2);
  } else {
    if (val1 > val2) {
      return 1;
    } else if (val1 < val2) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, if the data types are different, it returns 0. Check the new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pvgfkq7/1/)

Comment: it's fixed, can you check ?

Comment: `nil` doesn't exist in javascript, it's `null`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner for *current js* ES2020?:

```js
const spaceship = (a, b) => (a ?? 0).toString().localeCompare((b ?? 0).toString());
```

Returns string comparison for everything.

Comment: As this uses string comparison for numbers, it can give invalid results for inputs with a different quantity of digits, e.g. `spaceship(100, 2)` will result in `-1` (as it's effectively sorting alphabetically and the first "letter", `1` is "less" than `2`)

Comment: As this uses string comparison for everything, objects and arrays will not sort... as their string representation will be '[object Object]' and that is equal to itself. 0 is neither -1 or 1.