# Support older browsers with gulp

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp

I want to support es6 syntax and new features of javascript all the way to IE11. I am using gulp in my project. Is there any way so that the new javascript gets transpiled to support older browsers?

Comment: Use babel https://babeljs.io/  and polyfill for IE11 https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

Comment: Never used either gulp or babel but a quick test shows that babel doesn't support the spaceship operator ("abc" <=> 42).

Comment: @jeff there is no spaceship operator in JS (which OP is asking for and babeljs only transpiles) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852855/combined-comparison-spaceship-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @dippas, oops got my languages confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) which is the package of the [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) transpiler

by installing it like this: (for `babel 7`)

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-babel @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

the basic setup is something like this:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp'),
  babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', () =>
  gulp.src('src/yourJSfile.js')
  .pipe(babel({
    presets: ['@babel/env'] // the minimum presets needed to make gulp-babel work in babel 7 - https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/tree/v7-maintenance
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```