# what makes an operator <=> in the block min?

Tags: ruby

Have following example of code:

```
%w{ Ruby C APL Perl Smalltalk}.min {|a,b| a.size <=> b.size}
```

return "C"

Can you explain me why "C"? What makes an operator "<=>" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spaceship operator returns -1 if the left is less than the right, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if the left is greater than the right.

In this case, you're comparing the length of each word in the array and returning the shortest word. If you removed `.size` from the variable in the block, it would instead return the first word that occurs alphabetically (i.e. 'APL').

[What is the Ruby <=> (spaceship) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator)