# Get the min from an array of instances of multiple classes

Tags: ruby

In a Ruby app, I have an array that may contain instances of the Ruby `Date` class and instances of my `MissingDate` class.

Now, I need to get the `min` (or have `sort` working) from the array. So, I'm looking for the method I need to define in the `MissingDate` class in order to make `min` work but that proofs to be more difficult than anticipated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify "to make `min` work". Do you want to simply determine the earliest date, disregarding `MissingDate` objects?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/min) you need to [implement Comparable](https://apidock.com/ruby/Comparable).

In your `MissingDate` include Comparable and define the [spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/827656/7987708) (`<=>`).

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to extract the `Date` objects and then find the earliest.

```
require 'date'
```

```
class MissingDate
end
```

```
arr = [Date.parse("17 Apr 21"), MissingDate.new, Date.parse("1 Jan 21"),
       MissingDate.new, Date.parse("31 Mar 21")]
```

```
arr.grep(Date).min
  #=> #<Date: 2021-01-01 ((2459216j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

If `arr` contains no `Date` objects `nil` is returned.

Comment: You can also do `arr.grep(Date)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This could be an option.