# When did the spaceship operator <=> first appear?

Tags: spaceship-operator

A number of computer programming languages include the spaceship operator <=>.

I was wondering which computer programming language included it first, and when that was.

Comment: Apparently [tag:history] tag wiki suggests that your question is off-topic. Wikipedia lists some languages in [Three-way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison), guess you can start with checking which of these languages made this operator first, and where it come from.

Comment: This answer might be correct saying Perl and Ruby are the first to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/827656/2945027